# Pandas : Add 2 time columns and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to Pandas and was wondering if this is possible.

I have two columns one with epoch time and another with milliseconds count. I want to create a 3rd column, that has time in milliseconds using both of these as single time column that has time in ms, so that I can easily select data frame between given times. Could someone please help me with this.

```
my_time         my_ms_counts
1500702208      1
1500702208      2
1500702208      3
1500702208      4
1500702208      5
```

With these 2 I want a single time column.

Comment: by a "single time column" do you mean a datetime value such that the first row would be `2017-07-22 05:43:28.001`? Or are you looking to keep the time a float?

Comment: any kind of time should be fine. I tried your approach you described below and it works perfect to create new columns. But I thought it would be easy to get dataframe for the the selected time frame, but I always get empty dataframe when trying:                                                                                                         self.df[(self.df['DateTimeTS'] >= datetime.strptime(start_timestamp_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))]                                                                                                start_timestamp_str looks like '2020-06-10 11:01:12.161'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` will convert your epoch time to a date (specify **s**econds for the unit), then use `pd.to_timedelta` to add the milliseconds.

```
df['datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['my_time'], unit='s') 
                  + pd.to_timedelta(df['my_ms_counts'], unit='ms'))

#      my_time  my_ms_counts                datetime
#0  1500702208             1 2017-07-22 05:43:28.001
#1  1500702208             2 2017-07-22 05:43:28.002
#2  1500702208             3 2017-07-22 05:43:28.003
#3  1500702208             4 2017-07-22 05:43:28.004
#4  1500702208             5 2017-07-22 05:43:28.005
```

---

Alternatively you can combine both columns after converting to a similar unit. Choose the smaller unit, `ms`, to avoid issues with imperfect `float64` representations.

```
df['full_time_ms'] = df['my_time']*1000 + df['my_ms_counts']

#      my_time  my_ms_counts                datetime   full_time_ms
#0  1500702208             1 2017-07-22 05:43:28.001  1500702208001
#1  1500702208             2 2017-07-22 05:43:28.002  1500702208002
#2  1500702208             3 2017-07-22 05:43:28.003  1500702208003
#3  1500702208             4 2017-07-22 05:43:28.004  1500702208004
#4  1500702208             5 2017-07-22 05:43:28.005  1500702208005
```

Now you could convert that single column specifying `ms`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['full_time_ms'], unit='ms')

#0   2017-07-22 05:43:28.001
#1   2017-07-22 05:43:28.002
#2   2017-07-22 05:43:28.003
#3   2017-07-22 05:43:28.004
#4   2017-07-22 05:43:28.005
#Name: full_time_ms, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum both columns over a new one:

```
df['new_column']=df['my_time']+df['my_ms_counts']
```

If you need a new column with the timestamp date you can do:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new_column'],unit='s')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `my_time` is in seconds (since the start of the UNIX epoch) and `my_ms_counts` is a number of milliseconds you wish to add.

If you want a new column adding the two together, with units of milliseconds (since the start of the epoch), you need to multiply `my_time` by 1000 and add `my_ms_counts`.

This would do the trick:

```py
df["ms"] = 1000 * df["my_time"] + df["my_ms_counts"]
```

as would this:

```py
df["ms"] = df.my_time.mul(1000).add(df.my_ms_counts)
```

(if you prefer method chaining)

However, if I were you I would spend some time looking into `pandas` support for datetime operations. This will be much easier to work with for your application. You can start by parsing your columns into `pandas.Timestamp` objects. The specific operation you wanted can be achieved as follows:

```py
df["new_dt_col"] = (
      pd.to_datetime(df.my_time, unit='s')
    + pd.to_timedelta(data.my_ms_counts, unit="ms")
)
```

Note how this parses the `my_time` column into `Timestamp` objects and the `my_ms_counts` into `Timedelta` objects, which can be added to the timestamps.